# Facing issue with having generic as return type in Golang

Tags: go, generics

I'm invoking a function from another library whose return signature is defined as under:

```
(*studentlib.Student[StudentResponse], error)
```

`Student` is defined as:

```
type Student[T any] struct {
    st *students.Student
    xyz *T
}
```

`StudentResponse` is defined as:

```
type StudentResponse struct {
    
}
```

In my method signature, where I defined the return type as follows:

```
func abc() (*studentlib.Student[StudentResponse], error) {
   // do something here
}
```

But for the function return parameters, I keep getting errors like the following:

```
missing ',' in parameter list
```

Can someone please help here? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you post an example with a playground link to reproduce this? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of go are you using? From what I understand, generics weren't available until version 1.18. If you are using version 1.18 or above, I would first off try to give different names to your Student structs. It's a little confusing from a readability standpoint to have multiple structs name Student.

Getting into the issue, I think the biggest problem is that your 'abc' function has no way to know what generic type it needs to return since it's not taking an argument. Also, your 'abc' func needs to have the generic type included in the declaration.

A few smaller issues. Your StudentResponse struct should be an interface instead. Separate the specific data types that you want to included by the '|' char.

With that being said, here is how you would get your code to work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Student[T any] struct {
    st string
    xyz T
}

type StudentResponse interface {
    int64 | float64
}

func main() {
    tmp1 := Student[int64]{ // will not throw an error. generic type is defined in StudentResponse
        st: "Testing",
        xyz: 15,
    }
    /*tmp2 := Student[string]{ // will throw an error if used in 'abc' func. generic type not defined in Student Response
        st: "Testing",
        xyz: "15",
    }*/
    
    resp, err := abc(&tmp1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}

func abc[T StudentResponse](s *Student[T]) (*Student[T], error) {
    // do something here
    err := fmt.Errorf("error: %s", "some error") // being used simply to have an error return value
    return s, err
 }
```

If you want to use a pointer for xyz in student, you could do it this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Student[T any] struct {
    st string
    xyz *T
}

type StudentInfo struct {
    Age float64
    Weight  int64
}

type StudentGrades struct {
    GPA float64
    CreditHours int64
}

type StudentResponse interface {
    StudentInfo | StudentGrades
}

func main() {
    info := StudentInfo{
        Age: 22.5,
        Weight: 135,
    }
    grades := StudentGrades{
        GPA: 3.6,
        CreditHours: 15,
    }
    tmp1 := Student[StudentInfo]{
        st: "tmp1",
        xyz: &info,
    }
    tmp2 := Student[StudentGrades]{
        st: "tmp2",
        xyz: &grades,
    }
    
    resp1, err1 := abc(&tmp1)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err1)
    }

    resp2, err2 := abc(&tmp2)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp1)
    fmt.Println(resp1.xyz)

    fmt.Println(resp2)
    fmt.Println(resp2.xyz)
}

func abc[T StudentResponse](s *Student[T]) (*Student[T], error) {
    // do something here
    err := fmt.Errorf("error: %s", "some error") // being used simply to have an error return value
    return s, err
 }
```

Comment: Great job giving your first answer! Thanks. I would suggest you tweak this sentence:

"A few smaller issues, but your StudentResponse..."

so it is two sentences without the awkward "but". Like this:

"A few smaller issues. Your StudentResponse..."

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't even thinking about that but you're 100% right. Anything else that you think I should change? I'm still somewhat new to generics, so I'm not sure if the wording I used sometimes is correct or not